# How to render dom element based on value of passed prop?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a `Text` component that has a prop `as`, this can be any valid text dom element i.e. `<Text as="p" />` or `<Text as="h1" />`. Within component itself I want to render respective dom element and thus far I ended up with a big switch statement for this, however I am wondering if there is a better approach that is less verbose?

I tried looking at ui libs like chakra and material ui that have same patter, but quiet frankly wasn't able to figure it out form there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with this I discovered that react has `React.createElement` function that takes in dom element strings like `a` or `h1` for example, so to achieve my goals all I had to do was

```
return React.createElement('a', otherProps)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would then have an object store it somewhere outside of your component like in constants called e.g htmlOptionTag there you can have every expected props "as" :

```
const htmlOptionTag = {
  "a": ({label, ...rest}) => <a {...rest}>{label}</a>,
  "div": ({text, ...rest}) => <div {...rest}>{text}</div>,
  .....
};
```

Then import and use it inside Text component :

```
return htmlOptionTag[as](props) || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function `domElement` and it accepts two parameters :
tag and their attributes.

```
/**
 * @param {*} tag "a"
 * @param {*} attr {"href":"https://example.com", "class":"custom-class"}
 * @returns 
 */
const domElement = (tag, attr)=>{
  let ele = document.createElement(tag);
  if(Object.keys(attr).length > 0){
    for(let i in attr){
      ele.setAttribute(i,attr[i]);
    }
  }
  return ele;
}
```

Now if you run `domElement("a", {"href":"https://example.com", "class":"custom-class"})`
It will return :
`<a href="https://example.com" class="custom-class"></a>`

**Note** : You can also pass function as `{"onclick" : ()=>{console.log("I am  a function")}}`

You can also tweak my answer to **ReactJS** specific. I don't have much time right now, so I just gave you a hint on how you can minimize your code without having `ifelse` or `switch` statements.